# How do you force a timeout on testNG tests running during a maven test goal?

Tags: java, maven-2, testng

I see how to put timeouts on individual testng tests, but not on the maven test goal.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a similar problem right now. What you can do is, you create a [testng.xml](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml) and [reference it from your pom](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html#Using_Suite_XML_Files).

The problem here is, you'll have to do this for each module and I'm trying to configure it once in a central location but, when you reference src/test/resources/testng.xml, maven will resolve this to ${projectdir}/src/test/resources/testng.xml and so you need that file in every module of your project.

Oh and: if you specify a different timeout in the @Test annotation, then that will overwrite your timeout from the xml file, if the timeout of the annotation is higher (as far as I can tell from skimming trough some of the testng source code).